# Can I use white LEDs in reverse parallel to select which one lights based on polarity?

Tags: led, reverse-bias

I have a setup where I'd like to select one (or neither) of 2 LEDs for reflected or transmitted illumination, but it's under vacuum and I only have a single BNC feedthrough (at least until more parts come).  Easiest would be flipping the polarity of the cables from the power supply.l

I recall two facts: first, white LEDs have a poor tolerance for reverse bias (so an antiparallel diode is used for protection); second, red/green LEDs connected antiparallel were common and the diodes protected each other.

So if I get 2 *typical* white LEDs from the parts bin and connect them anti-parallel, would this be expected to be enough to protect them from reverse breakdown?

I say typical for two reasons: I have some leftover that are suitable in terms of brightness and emission angle, but I have no paperwork for them; I'm interested in the general case - if this would work for most LEDs, I'll do it even when I have more parts, if not, I'll design something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. Most LEDs are rated at 5V reverse voltage, which is much less than the Vf of a blue LED.

Multiplexing LEDs also exposes them to similar reverse voltages, so every blue or white LED numeric display is probably operated the same way.

Comment: That's clearer than anything I've been able to find (partly why I asked the question) - thanks

Comment: In cases where the LED reverse voltage is not adequate, you can also just put a regular diode in series with each of the antiparallel LEDs.  Same direction.

Answer (score 1):

Reflective sensors may range from UV & yellow for paper money to IR for most other things.

It is possible to operate at +/- 5V with floating current limiting to drive the emitter and have a logic level drive the 0V floating to earth ground with an open collector and Zener limiter.  I.e. two way Tx/Rx on one cable assuming some case ground is avail.

Optical apertures isolate each sensor.